# Image cannot be read when pasted

Tags: javascript, html

I made a tool which converts images to base64 data.

```
<input id="inp" type='file'><br>
<br>
<textarea readonly placeholder="Base64 data" id="b64"></textarea>
<br>
<img id="img">
<script>
function readFile() {
  
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    
    var FR= new FileReader();
    
    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = e.target.result;
      document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
    }); 
    
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
  
}

window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  document.getElementById("inp").files = e.clipboardData.files;
});

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);

</script>
```

Image can be uploaded either by using `<input id="inp" type='file'>`, or by directly copying and pasting the image from clipboard onto the window.

Here is the problem; when image is uploaded through the usual `<input>`, it renders the base64 data within seconds, however when pasting the image from clipboard onto the window, the `input` seems to recognize the image as **image.png** but no data gets rendered. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the pasted URL is being "converted".

Comment: However in google chrome there is a recent feature called `copying images to the clipboard` it may help.